# C strtoll hex to unsigned long

Tags: c++, c

I have hex strings like this 769cb353f44f 37679162ec73.

When I use `strtoul(prt, null or ptr, 16)`, `strtoull(prt, null or ptr, 16)` or `strtoumax(prt, null or ptr, 16)` only last 8 bytes are converted into unsigned long.

Like this `ffffffffb353f44f` `ffffffff9162ec73`.

And I want these strings to be stored as digits which they represent.

Does anyone know how to solve this or at least why it happens?

Comment: This number is too big. What is `sizeof(unsigned long long)` on your system.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a code sample to help clarify your question.  I'm thinking maybe your numbers were inadvertently cast to a 32 bit value somewhere, but without a code sample it's hard to tell.

Comment: actual code is used parse data through blowfish algorythm. For some reason its output is 13 characters long sometimes 16 characters long strings starting with fff.... my formatting was as follows ` printf("%08lx %08lx", ul1, ul2); ` if i changed it to '%llx' output looked the same. so all in all, if i cannot transform those hex strings into unsigned long , decryption won't work. surprisingly encrypt/decrypt works fine if the data is not stored in a file.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the unsigned long long as the string are too big to fit in a unsigned long.

Then you also need to check you set the result to a unsigned long long AND print it using %llX (unsigned long long in hex format)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  const char * ptr = "769cb353f44f";
  unsigned long long num;

  num = strtoull(ptr, NULL, 16);

  printf("%llx\n", num);

  return 0;
}
```